# Why $x=5; $x+++$x++; equals with 11 in PHP?

Tags: php, opcode

According to the opcodes it should be 12. Am I getting it wrong?

```
number of ops:  8
compiled vars:  !0 = $x
line    #* E I O op                  fetch      ext   return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3     0  E >   EXT_STMT                                                 
        1        ASSIGN                                         !0, 5
  5     2        EXT_STMT                                                 
        3        POST_INC                               ~2      !0
        4        POST_INC                               ~3      !0
        5        ADD                                    ~4      ~2, ~3
        6        ECHO                                           ~4
  7     7      > RETURN                                         1

branch: #  0; line:     3-    7; sop:     0; eop:     7; out1:  -2
path #1: 0,
```

**Edit**

Also ($x++)+($x++); returns the same result (11). Actually this was the main reason for the question and opcode investigation.

Comment: From the example in the edit it looks like () have no effect on the POST_INC operations.

Comment: This code is not readable nor usefull. The behaviour can be changed with the next PHP release. Code more clean so everybody has a chance to understand it.

Comment: This question is related to how PHP works not code quality.

Comment: And again. This is a useless question because the code isn't clear and can be changed anytime by PHP in order to get rid of this mess. [Interesting article](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/?utm_source=tool.lu) - already 6 years old and many of the issues are fixed but lot of them not. I consider it useless asking a question like this in this Babylon project PHP.

Comment: It is not useless to me. The edit completes it. Why () do not change the expected behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took me a few reads, but `$x=5; $x++ + $x++;` works like this:

In the case of a $x++, it first 'gets used', then increased:

- `$x=5;` — Set $x to 5
- `$x++ + ...` — Use, then increment

  - Place $x onto formulae stack (which is 5)
  - Increment(`++`) ($x is now 6, stack=[**5**])
- `... + $x++;` — Use, then increment

  - Add $x onto stack (stack=[5,**6**], so 5+6 -> $x=11)
  - Adding is done, that outcome is 11
  - Increment $x(`++`) (which is isn't used further, but $x is now 7)

Actually, in this specific example, if you would `echo $x;`
it would output 7. You never reassign the value back to $x, so $x=7 (you incremented it twice);

Comment: What about ($x++)+($x++)? It still returns 11.

Comment: Same principle applies, Stack ($x), then ++ it ([5], $x=6), stack ($x), then ++ it ([5,6], $x=7). The parenthesis dont matter at all (confusing, I know)

Comment: @Emil just try `++$x + ++$x` and see the magic. Also try to understand 'preincrement ' and 'postincrement'

Answer (score 4):

```
$x = 5;
$a = $x++ + $x++;
```

**the expression line will be executed like this:**
1st occurrence of `$x++` in the statement will increment `$x` value by 1 so it will become 6 and

in 2nd occurrence, `$x` will be having value 6;

So $a = 5 + 6;

So final result `$a` will be 11.

Answer (score 3):

++ has higher precedence than + operator

(x++) will return the value of x first then increment it by 1

```
$x = 2
$x++ // return 2, then increment it to 3
```

x+++x++ is evaluated like the following

```
1. Get x value first which is 5
2. Then it will be incremented to 6
3. But first x value will be 5 because (x++) statement will return 5 first then increment the value
4. Then + operator is encountered
5. Next x will have 6 as value not 7 for the same reason (x++) will return the x value first and then increment it
6. So 5+6 is 11
7..At the end, x value will be 7
```

**Same goes for    `($x++)+($x++)`**

`grouping operator ()` has `left to right` associatevity. First `($x++)` executes first.

```
$x = 5
($x++) returns 5 and then increment $x by 1. Same as before.
```

then last ($x++) executes. It returns 6 and then increment $x to 7

so same `5+6 // 11` is returned back

Comment: What about ($x++)+($x++)? It still returns 11.

Comment: grouping operator which is () has associativity of  left to right. So left ( ) will execute first then the right one. So the same scenario happens

Answer (score 2):

The post increment operator increment the variable, but returns its old value.

So `$x++` is equivalent to:

```
($temp = $x, $x = $x + 1, $temp)
```

When you do it twice in an expression, it's like:

```
echo ($temp1 = $x, $x = $x + 1, $temp1) + ($temp2 = $x, $x = $x + 1, $temp2);
```

The first part sets `$temp1 = 5` and increments `$x` to `6`.

The second part sets `$temp2 = 6` and increments `$x` to 7.

Then it does `$temp1 + $temp2` and echoes the result, which is `5 + 6 = 11`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the post-increment operator ($x++). If you would like to use the incremented value for the addition you should use the pre-increment operator (++$x).

Therefore if $x = 5

```
$x++ + $x++ equals 5+6 = 11
++$x + $x++ equals 6+6 = 12
$x++ + ++$x equals 5+7 = 12
$++x + ++$x equals 6+7 = 13
```

Yet in all cases, x is equal to 7 afterward.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 5;
echo $x++ + $x++;
```

prints 11 as first $x++ returns 5 and then after that it increments, the second $x++ returns 6 and the only value in incremented. so actual addition is 5+6 which gives 11.

Answer (score 0):

++$x + $x++ will be 12

And ++$x + ++$x will be 13

when you use $x++ $x get +1 as soon it's value is use, but the value that will gonna be use is the one it has before the increment, so when yo do:

$x=5; $x+++$x++;

$x+++$x++ is 11, but $x will be 7